# MongoDb C# normal property to versioned property automatically

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, postsharp

I have this implementation of versioned property

```
public class VersionedProperty<T>: Dictionary<int, T>, IParentEntityTracker //where T:IComparable<T>
{
    [BsonIgnore]
    public IVersionableEntity ParentEntity { get; set; }

    public VersionedProperty()
    {
    }

    public VersionedProperty(IVersionableEntity parentEntity)
    {
        ParentEntity = parentEntity;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        set
        {
            var curVal = Value;
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(curVal, value))
                return;

            ParentEntity.AtLeastOneVersionedPropertyModified = true;
            this[ParentEntity.Version + 1] = value;
        }
        get
        {
            var key = ParentEntity.Version + (ParentEntity.AtLeastOneVersionedPropertyModified ? 1 : 0);
            var keys = Keys.Where(k => k<=key).ToList();
            if (!keys.Any())
                return default(T);
            var max = keys.Max();
            T res;
            TryGetValue(max, out res);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

Initially I created some property in the document as not versioned. Let say

```
public class Product
{
public Decimal Price{get;set;}
}
```

after some time I realized that I did mistake and I should use versioned property

```
public class Product
{
public VersionedProperty<Decimal> Price{get;set;}
}
```

What I would like is that old value in the existing document automatically deserialized into this versioned property to avoid writing update queries on the collection.
Is it possible somehow interfere with the process of deserializing?

May be this can help: I use postsharp to create empty instance of versioned property for autoproperties. My postsharp aspect also assigns reference of a parent entity to ParentEntity property of that newly created empty instance of the versioned property.

Comment: Have you looked at these docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#specifying-the-serializer If the dataset is small, I'd still suggest you just fix the data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah, I don't like specifying my serializer. I wanted simple solution. Yes, I can fix the data, but if it  can be done in a simple way I don't want write update queries which can potentially do something wrong with the data.

Comment: The only way I know of that's reasonable is in the link I included. Until all your data is converted, it will always need the extra overhead of the custom serializer.